# integer and float instructions in sparc

Tags: solaris, sparc, instruction-set

While working with SPARC-V9 instruction set, I am trying to classify some instructions as **Integer** or **Float**. I want to know do we categorize branch instructions as integer? What about NOP? What about load/store?

Another issue is, when I see

```
 LDF    Load Floating-Point Register
```

I don't know what to decide. Loading something in to a floating point register, is that an integer operation or float?

Already I have read some sections of sparc reference manual, however didn't end-up with a clear explanation which instructions are float and which are integer.

Answer (score 0):

That's up to you to decide and clarify your definition.

Depending on whether you define what is a "floating point instruction", for example the ones that involve some floating point computation or any instruction handling a floating point value, `LDF` will be or not part of the "Float" group.

Moreover, if you want only two groups, the other one should be "Anything else" instead of "Integer". `NOP`, just like all instructions that do not compute anything are undoubtedly neither "Floating Point" nor "Integer".